# string was not recognized as a valid datetime. in c#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

i am using this code for passing datetime.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text)
```

but the compiler show an error that string was not recognized as a valid datetime. so how to avoid this error and is a datetime field in my database.

Comment: What's the value of the input string ?

Comment: What's the value of `textBox1.Text`?  I'm guessing it's something that's not directly parseable into a `DateTime`.  How to avoid this error is to use a correct `DateTime` value, use something like `DateTime.TryParse()` to handle possible errors, etc.  This has nothing to do with your database field.

Comment: i normally enter like 01/01/2012

Comment: @SameerShaikh: What you "normally enter" is one thing, what the _actual_ value is at _runtime_ (note, not a "compiler error") when the error _occurs_ is a considerably more useful piece of information.  Have you not debugged this and checked the value?

Comment: actually i have to pass the two date to a method and the method will insert a record into a database. so i use Entry(fromdate,toDate) how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text)
```

This code will throw an exception if the `string` value in `textBox1.Text` doesn't represent a valid `DateTime` (or at least can't be parsed into one with default functionality in C#).  You can add some defensive programming to handle errors like this.

The `DateTime` type (as well as most, if not all, common value types in .NET) has [a method on it called `TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) specifically for the purpose to attempting to parse a value into that type without throwing an exception.  The method returns `true` if the parse was successful, `false` otherwise.  And it accepts an `out` parameter to hold the resulting parsed value (or the original value if parsing is unsuccessful).

So instead of this:

```
var dateTimeValue = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
```

You could use something like this:

```
var dateTimeValue = DateTime.MinValue;
if (DateTime.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out dateTimeValue))
    // use the value for something
```